# Time zone editor

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, time-zone

Is there any program similar to [Time Zone Editor](http://www.softshape.com/cham/manual/tzedit.htm) but for newer versions of Windows (Vista and later)?

It's purpose was to create new time-zones with their own rules and with custom naming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [procedure](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914387) how to change time zone directly in Registry Editor. It works by dumping data of one time-zone to .reg file, changing that data and then injecting new data back in registry.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Vista/7 support DST by default, and also allow you to specify multiple clocks with different times... does the software do more than that?

Comment: That software supported creating time-zones with custom name.